# Insert value to table at a specific index using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am facing some challenges with a code I am working on. I have multiple select tags (eg color, size etc) from which you can make selections. Each value selected from the different select tags is inserted in a td tag in a table. The select tags can be assessed at random so from header as below

| SN | Color | Size | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

When you select size "3" from the "Size" drop down, the table should be populated as below

| SN | Color | Size | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. |  | 3 |  |

The problem I have is that even though the headers are fixed, I cannot seem to be able to insert/update that single td to be as above expected result.

What I have tried:

`var size = $(this).find('option:selected').text();`
//Works fine

```
$('table tbody tr td').eq(1).after('<td>'+size+'</td>');
```

The above inserts the value but shifts everything to the right and that row ends up being more than the number of headers. (Not what I want)

I have also tried other thing which I know are incorrect.

Also, if someone could help with a way to make sure I am updating the particular row. What I did was to subtract 1 from SN ie (sn-1).
Hope my question is clear about my intent here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `data-` attribute on each select to identify the column index like:

```
<select data-col="1">
```

Simple example:

```js
// just to add some option values
initDemo();


$('select').change(function(){
   const tableCol = $(this).data('col'),
         text = $(this).find(':selected').text()
   $('tbody td').eq(tableCol).text(text);
});


function initDemo() {
  const data = [
    ['Green', 'Red', 'Blue'],
    ['Large', 'Medium', 'Small'],
    [1, 4, 10]
  ];

  data.forEach((arr, i) => $('select').eq(i).append(arr.map(v => new Option(v, v))))

}
```

```css
td{width:60px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Color :
<select data-col="1">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>


Size :
<select data-col="2">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>

Qty :
<select data-col="3">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>

<hr/>

<table  border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SN</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```